# GRASS: Extend Map Display canvas to full window

Tags: grass-gis

This has been a feature of the 7.8 releases, the map canvas in the Map Display does not extend to the full window.

[image]

The size of the map canvas seems to be hard-coded somehow, no matter the size of the window the canvas is always the same size. This is not always critical, but with large maps it becomes difficult to visualise the whole thing.

Is there any way to force the map canvas to extend to the full window size? I work on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Which GRASS GIS 7.8.x version is this precisely? Looks like this problem: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/1262

Comment: @markusN I had this issue at least with 7.8.0 and 7.8.2. The print screens above are from 7.8.2. Following the link, I understood this problem was address in 7.8.3. I just installed 7.8.5 (from ubuntugis-unstable) and indeed with this latest version the canvas is used in full.

Comment: Glad it is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears, according to https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/1262 that the problem has been fixed in GRASS GIS 7.8.5, available from https://grass.osgeo.org/download/